# Select clause with If condition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a query within 2 tables.

I have one table with id_person and message: (addedEvent) and other table with id_person, names and surnames. (registered)

The problem is that messages can be related to one person (id_person) or to everyone (id_person = 0) so I want to take the name and the surname of every person when needed and not not when not needed. I tried this:

```
SELECT message,
       IF(id_person!= 0,
          SELECT name
          FROM registered
          WHERE addedEvents.id_person= registered.id_person, 0) AS name,
       IF(id_person!= 0,
          SELECT surname
          FROM registered
          WHERE addedEvents.id_person= registered.id_person, 0) AS surname
FROM addedEvents
```

But gives me a syntax error  and I don't see it.

Comment: The above code is missing the parentheses for the inner `SELECT` clauses. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't think of SQL as a regular programming language with flow control structures and the like. And your query does not even seem to need it:

```
SELECT ae.message, re.name, re.surname
FROM addedEvents ae
LEFT JOIN registered re ON ae.id_person=re.id_person
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. I have to read about mysql because my knowledge is very basic.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT message,
    IF(
        id_person != 0,
        (
            SELECT name 
            FROM registered 
            WHERE addedEvents.id_person = registered.id_person
        ),
        '0'
    ) AS name,
    IF(
        id_person != 0,
        (
            SELECT surname
            FROM registered 
            WHERE addedEvents.id_person = registered.id_person
        ),
        '0'
    ) AS surname
FROM addedEvents
```

Comment: @Biribu: The error was due to missing parentheses. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to select message of a related person in registered.

**Try this**:

```
select
        r.name, r.surname, e.message
  from 
        addedEvents e, registered r
where 
        e.id_person = r.id_person
  and   r.id_person != 0
```

Comment: I want all messages, related to a person and general. but if it is a general message, appear a not not or something in name and surname

Comment: Your comment is not understandable. What is *`if it is a general message, appear a not not or something in name and surname`*

Comment: General message is a message with id_person = 0. That means that message is for all persons. Sorry, my english i s not vey good